# How do I order categorical data in SQL to match a list of names?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

How would I order a column of categories based on a specified (and ordered) list of just those category names?

For example, let's say the names of groups `a`, `b`, and `c`, are listed in descending order based on their respective group mean blood pressure as `[b,a,c]` (with `b` having the highest mean blood pressure, and `c` the lowest). Going back to the full dataset, how could I organize, say 100 rows, by order of the category in that list, and then by individual blood pressure.

Here's what I guessed, and this didn't work.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM data
ORDER BY category IN (SELECT category FROM data
                      GROUP BY category
                      ORDER BY AVG(blood_pressure) DESC)
```

I would still like to order by individual blood pressure within their respective groups, but ideally have all the rows grouped first by their category mean.

Comment: What is the negative vote for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this -- join to the "table" that contains what you want to sort on then specify that in the order by, in your case we can create the table to use in a sub-select.

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
JOIN (
  SELECT category,  AVG(blood_pressure)  as AVG_BP 
  FROM data
  GROUP BY category
) x on x.category = data.category
ORDER BY AVG_BP DESC
```

Comment: This worked. Any idea how to select columns? It seems to have returned everything, and will not let me select from the first line (i.e. needs '*' to be present to work)

Comment: @Yacob yes you list the column names after the select keyword instead of using `*` -- this is very very very very very basic SQL

Comment: apologies. I wrote that question on my first day of learning SQL. The reason I asked the follow up is because I am unable to select columns of interest in the first line i.e. only works when `*` is present. I am returned with an ambiguous column name error. This does solve the question I posed albeit in not the most elegant of fashions. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Yacob it is because the column name is in both data (the table) and x (the sub-query), use `data.category` or `x.category` to solve the ambiguous error.  Also very cute telling me my code is not elegant -- please show me a more elegant way Mr. "3 days of learning SQL" :D

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS supports window functions, you can do:

```
select *
from data d
order by 
    avg(blood_pressure) over(partition by category) desc,
    blood_pressure desc
```